# Is it true that $\sup\{|a+b|\} \leq \sup\{|a| + |b|\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Is it true that $\sup\{|a+b|\} \leq \sup\{|a| + |b|\}$? I am trying to argue that the statement in the last sentence is true and all I can think about to argue for it is that we know that $|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$ and so the $\sup$ of the left side will always be less than or equal than the right hand side. Can anyone tell me if this reasoning is enough to justify the inequality or if I need to think about something else?

Comment: Thanks @Mattos, I corrected it!

Comment: Seems enough to me, though if you're not sure it might be instructive to give a very careful argument where you use the formal definition of $\sup,$ etc.

Comment: You can proove it by contradiction too.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using this result to prove something else, but I just wasn't sure if I could use this type of argument just like that.

Comment: If $f(x) \le g(x)$ then $\sup f \le \sup g$.

Comment: sup {|a|+|b|} >= |a|+|b|  >= |a+b| for all a,b.  Sup {|a|+|b|} is an upper bound of {|a+b|} and thus larger or equal to sup {|a+b|}.  But, um, how are the a and b determined? What *are* the sets {|a+b|} or {|a+b|} exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Show that the right side is an upper bound on $\{|a+b|\}$. Since the $sup$ is the least upper bound you will have proven the inequality.